# how to produce the most listed item in list in python

Tags: python

I want to produce print the most listed item in a list

for example,

```
aList = ["SE","CpE","SE","CS","CS","SE"]
```

and result should be

```
aList = ["SE"]
```

which is the most listed item.
Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter(aList)
a.most_common()[0]
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of such questions, but anyway.

You can do this using stdlib's `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter(aList)
a.most_common()[0]
```

Or you can write your own class/function:

```
def count(list):
    items = {}
    for item in list:
        if item not in items:
            items[item] = 0
        items[item] += 1
    return items

>>> count(["SE","CpE","SE","CS","CS","SE"])
{"SE": 3,...}
```